# Is it possible to persist an RDD on HDFS?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I know that an RDD can be persisted/cache on memory, disk or both, but is it possible to also persist it on the HDFS. The problem I am facing is that I have too little memory and disk space on my cluster, while my HDFS space is huge.

Comment: is HDFS and worker nodes are in different cluster/nodes ? if so, to my understanding its not possible.

Comment: Yes... There's a few methods to save to HDFS. What did you try to research before asking?

Comment: I believe the RDD content needs to be collected in full on some worker before it can be placed into HDFS, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried saveAsTextFile/saveAsObjectFile, but I want a better method. That is, one in which worker nodes can directly write to the HDFS.

Comment: What do you mean with _better method_ ? Why not converting it to a DataFrame and save it as a table ?

Comment: Like I said, I think the RDD needs collected before can be written. I don't think individual workers can open consecutive file streams to write a sequential file in HDFS

Comment: I was working with RDDs. But DataFrame is one thing I would like to look at if that solves my problem. Can this DataFrame table be stored in the HDFS without involving the driver node?

Comment: Have you looked at OFF_HEAP persistence using Tachyon?

Comment: @Anas, OFF_HEAP persistence will still use the system memory, right? Like I said I don't have enough of it in my cluster.

Comment: If you are using Tachyon as OFF_HEAP, it can be configured to use HDFS memory instead for data persistence. It is fast as well. Have a look at Tachyon installation and configuration with Spark and Hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

RDD persist is possible up to within worker machine(memory and disk) only. Some persistence levels make a replica of RDD in other worker machines in cluster.

As of today in order to persist RDD/DataFrame in HDFS, we have to use write API only.

**Writing to HDFS:**

```
// Writing DataFrame
df.write.save("hdfs://namenode_host:port/file/path"); 

//Writing RDD
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://namenode_host:port/file/path", "codec_if_any");
```

[RDD Persistence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

Comment: Does this involve the driver node, or the workers can directly write to the HDFS? I mean is there collection on the driver side going on in this case?

Comment: Driver will pass this command to Worker nodes and they execute it.

Comment: but i think its action not persist RDD its saving result in the file because its action m i right?

Comment: @SandeepPurohit: Yes, it's writing. I added this according to his response to cricket_007.

Comment: @MRSrinivas okok i thought he ask about about persistence of RDD on OFF_HEAP HDFS